# How can I monitor load average CPU other servers via monit tools?

Tags: monitoring, monit

How can I monitor load average CPU  other servers via monit tools?

this example shows the only localhost.

```
   check System my_server
    if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
    if memory usage > 12% then alert
    if swap usage > 25% then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 80% then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 30% then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 20% then alert
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot configure a particular `monit` directly with rules for other servers as your example.

The `monit` daemon configuration only pertains to the particular server where it is installed; e.g. `monit` by itself is only the (remote) `agent` running on the server/VM.

However, you can:

- use [M/Monit](https://mmonit.com) for talking with and collecting `monit` data from a central server over the network;
- configure monit for accessing each monit instance individually via a browser;
- use monit as an agent for Nagios.

As for `M/monit`, it is also made by the guys that wrote `monit`, but is paid. It is an interesting lightweight monitoring solution for a small infra-structure, and has general hosts monitoring, analytics, and the interface also works well in mobile devices.

See [M/Monit screenshots](https://web.archive.org/web/20180818210944/https://mmonit.com/screenshots/)

For M/Monit to talk with `monit`, you have to activate the web interface, in each `monit` instance. Activating the web interface aside from giving a web interface, also allows access to a REST API giving XML statistics that can be accessed remotely.

To activate the web interface either for M/Monit, or for being able to browse remotely the monitoring data:

> ```
> set httpd port 2812   
> allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0     # allow localhost to connect to the server  
> allow admin:monit
> ```

See also [Install and Configure Monit web interface](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/install-and-configure-monit-web-interface/)

After configuring a monit web interface, you can also use a browser and point directly to the particular server/VM.

Nevertheless, for monitoring several server, I prefer using Nagios or Zabbix.

While there are Nagios plug-ins for monit, I prefer using the native `agent`, `nrpe`.

There is also a python library to talk remotely with `monit` via the web interface, which my allow you to script your way for monitoring a couple of servers, I have not explored that avenue. https://github.com/polymeris/python-monit

Example of monit web interface:

[image: monit]
<sub>(source: [sleeplessbeastie.eu](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/assets/uploads/2014/10/monit_1.png))</sub>